# How to remove band from stack in ERDAS 2013?

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, digital-image-processing, landsat-8

I have a Landsat 8 scene where I have stacked 11 bands.  I need to remove one band from the stacked layer.  Is there a toolbox in ERDAS 2013 that allows me to take out a band?

I am aware that ENVI 5.1 has a tool, resize, that does this. The problem if I save the new file in ENVI and I want to open the file in ERDAS it may not read properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Layer Stack tool in reverse by using your 11 band stack as the input and selecting only the bands you want in the output.  For example, in the attached screenshot I added bands 1, 2, 3 to the stack (omitting band 4).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The stacked I did had resampled from 30m to 15m and how can you reverse backed to 30m when you need to stack them again ?

Comment: You must have included the panchromatic band (15m res) in the original stack.  Can you go back to the original data and do a stack without the panchromatic band and the other band your refer to?  The only alternative would be to resample to 30m, though this is not recommended.

Comment: Yes you got that right.