# Unstack band layers from raster

Tags: raster, landsat, erdas-imagine, band, stack

I have stacked layer (from ERDAS) of Landsat 1-5 and 7, bands. I want each of the bands in a separate layer. How can I do that?

Comment: Use the Make Raster Layer tool choosing the appropriate band.

Comment: this is something new... i ll try it.

Comment: have you solved the problem yet? you can use model maker to unstack your raster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spatial Model Editor in erdas can be used to solve your problem. I already made  a simple model, you can download from [this gmdx model](http://www.filedropper.com/unstacking) .

Model Thumbnail :
[image]

Comment: yeah. it can be solved using stack layer in reverse order or by using simple raster function in ENVI modeler against each band and saving their output to separately.

Answer (score 2):

I know this an old question, but here is another way to unstack multiband-image. The solution is done using QGIS with Orfeo toolbox installed. You can use `split image tool` from Orfeo toolbox. The `Split Image`, as you can see below, will split the multiband-image that you have into separate images, and each image has one band.

[image]

You need to specify an output filename. The output filename will be used to get the prefix and the extension of the output images to write.

In the example above, I just put `Image.tif`. You can choose any name you prefer.

However, Orfeo toolbox is not downloaded by default into QGIS. You need to download it separately, or better use OSGeo4W advanced install to download Orfeo toolbox from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have already solved this but I had the same issue as your are...but here is the solution for you to unstack your bands to individual band you want.

[How to remove band from stack in ERDAS 2013?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142839/how-to-remove-band-from-stack-in-erdas-2013)

Comment: please add more detail, not just the link. The name of the main command, fat least.

Comment: I do not remember when I post it but this is when I did at the old job. I will try and find the info somewhere with me. I am current at a new job and been here for a year...